# can I add graphql

Tags: rest, graphql

I have recently switched from rest to graphql. Now I have already had two clients (companies) that refuse to consume graphql and demand REST. 
I am basically forced to maintain both APIs. What is a low maintenance way to keep both systems running and synced? Should I just focus on REST again and then wrap the endpoints in a graphql schema?

It seems that graphql is great when used within a corporation when you have full control over the consumers. However, when using it for a public API one basically needs to have REST as well at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `/graphql` endpoint to your rest API, share same services under the hood.

Comment: Nonetheless I would have to maintain two systems. REST endpoints and the graphql schema/resolvers